# How to show that $ \mathcal{B}=\{[a,b)| a<b, (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$ is a base of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Suppose you have $\mathcal{B}=\{[a,b)| a<b, (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$. Show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base of a topology $\mathcal{O}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then show that the usual open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the open sets of $\mathcal{O}$.

I just started studying the bases of topology. If I understand correctly, I gotta first show that $\mathcal{B}$ covers $\mathcal{O}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, I am unsure what $\mathcal{O}$ stands exactly here. For the case of $\mathbb{R}$, for any element $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \in [a,b)$ for a $b > a$, thus $\mathcal{B}$ covers $\mathbb{R}$ (not sure what to do with $\mathcal{O}$). If now $[a,b)$ and $[c,d) \in \mathcal{B}$, then as long as $b>c$, we have $[a,b) \cap [c,d) = [b,c) \in \mathcal{B}$. So is it complete?

And now for the second question, I am unsure what $\mathcal{O}$ really stands for. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to show $\mathcal{B}$ is a base is:

- As you said, to show that it's a cover of the set (in this case, $\mathbb{R}$), and
- for any two basis elements $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}$, and for every $x$ in $B_1\cap B_2$, to show there is a third basis element $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ in their intersection containing $x$, i.e. $x \in B_3\subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

$\mathcal{O}$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$; we have $U\in\mathcal{O}$ iff $U=\cup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} B_\lambda$ for some collection of elements in $\mathcal{B}$. Equivalently, $U\in\mathcal{O}$ iff for every $x\in U$ there is some $B\in\mathcal{B}$ with $x\in B \subseteq U$.

You've got part 1 OK. Hopefully this helps with part 2.

Comment: Part 2 should be $\forall x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ there exists $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

Comment: yes, thanks! Edited.